repo sync succeeds but make fails：Segmentation fault
I'm building AOSP10.0.0.r1 using Ubuntu20.04, lunch aosp_x86-eng, but I encountered the following error.Until then, I followed the instructions on the aosp website completely.
clang++: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang++: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Android (5484270 based on r353983c) clang version 9.0.3
......
ninja failed with: exit status 1
There is no official developer community to ask or find similar questions

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
